# Force ubuntu to access internet through proxy

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

I've set up a squid forward proxy to cache all internet requests. I have a public ip and opened port 3128. Now I just need to set my ubuntu server to force all internet connections to pass through this proxy, using the ip address and port number.

I know this command which will make ubuntu access the internet via a proxy, but I was told it wasn't permanent.

`export http_proxy="http://proxy.example.com:8080"`

Which command do I need to use to force ubuntu to go through this proxy regardless of reboots or sessions?

Thanks

Comment: Put that line into your `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 2):

You have to [set some settings in `/etc/environment`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175172/how-do-i-configure-proxies-in-ubuntu-server-or-minimal-cli-ubuntu) to make it permanent:

> - Open the `/etc/environment` file with `vi` (or your favorite editor). This file stores the system-wide variables initialized upon
>     boot.
> - Add the following lines, modifying appropriately. You must duplicate in both upper-case and lower-case because (unfortunately) some
>     programs only look for one or the other:
>
>   ```
>    http_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
>   https_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
>   ftp_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
>   no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
>   HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
>   HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
>   FTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
>   NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
>   ```
> - `apt-get`, `aptitude`, etc. will not obey the environment variables when used normally with `sudo`. So separately configure them; create a
>     file called `95proxies` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`, and include the
>     following:
>
>   ```
>    Acquire::http::proxy "http://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
>   Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
>   Acquire::https::proxy "https://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
>   ```
>
> Finally, logout and reboot to make sure the changes take effect.

Comment: Right, I've performed all of the steps and added the settings. However CGI scripts seem to ignore the rules. What do I need to do to have CGI scripts also obey them?

Comment: Do you have logged out and in after you changed it?

Comment: Well I've rebooted the server.. so shouldn't that mean I've logged in and out? But still CGI scripts that make internet connections outside seem to ignore the environment wide rules

Comment: do we still need to configure url in the browser to access internet through proxy ?? ( eq. inside  firefox settings > Configure proxies to access internet  )

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solution can't work in the general case - it assumes that everything will acknowledge and use the Environment variable.

In order to make this work for HTTP, you need to set u a "Transparent Proxy", which generally requires IPTABLES nat rules to capture and redirect the traffic.  Have a look [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html) for how to do this.

Doing the same thing for HTTPS is practical but you will need to additionally install a CA in SQUID and accept it in the Ubuntu box so it can intercept the traffic.

This might not be practical with FTP (I've not tried it)